# Google Analytics structure for 8 related websites

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I'm a little confused about the structure that I need to use in google analytics.

I'm working for a group that has 8 websites (domains), that are all centralized.

Do I need to use 8 properties (different Google analytics UI ID)? or can I have 1 property and 8 views?

If the answer is views; Then how can I track this views separately , Do I need  to add a value or property to the Analytics code or GTM options??

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create a different property for each distinct site (so 8 properties), and then also create one more property that's a rollup (optional). Your tags would send data to two properties (one site prop and one rollup prop). In GTM, depending on whether you have one container per site, or one container for all sites. If the former, then you would have one property for each container. If the latter, then you would use a lookup table and pivot off the hostname.

Having 1 property and 8 views is possible, but it really depends on how different or similar your sites are. With 8 views, you would need a filter to identify which property to send data to.

Comment: Thank you @nyuen , I really would like to know how to Filter the views, wha would be the steps to achieve this?

Comment: Your view filters would necessarily include an "Include Hostname" filter that only permits data to a particular domain (eg. www.site1.com, or www.site2.com, etc.). Once you have one of these filters for EACH of your views, then you pretty much have the data separation down pat. Make sure you do NOT include multiple include filters within a view as they cannot be chained. Also, make sure your filter is the FIRST filter in the view, as filters are applied starting with the first one and going down.